# Is XSLT being executed?

Tags: xml, xslt

According to our teacher, XSLT is being executed. We (2 students) think it's not. We think it's being processed. When we got the question on our tests, we answered wrong, according to our teacher. Thus being our question, **Is XSLT being executed, or is it being processed?**

### Why do we have doubts?

Well, we think that because XSLT is XML, the document is being parsed as XML, than being read and *not* executed.

*BTW, we will be rewarded more points on our test's result!*

**Update:** We are working on getting the test's question posted and translated here.

**Sources that makes our doubts even more doubtful:**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767587(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider another high-level language like Python. Is it executed or processed? The python interpreter processes the file, sure, but the python script holds instructions that are executed. So the Python script is executed.

The same thought goes for XSLT: the XSLT processor reads the template patterns and templates are executed on a node match (the templates determine the execution path). There are native code generators for XSLT, and you can even call native code (C++/Java) within an xslt.

Comment: I agree. The best why I can explain it is; XSLT syntax is set of instructions that are applied to the parsed xml, therefore the XSLT is executed.